# C++11 Return value and error pair

Tags: c++, c++11, error-handling, runtime-error

As C++11 introduced move semantics, I am wondering if the function could return both value and operation status. Actually, it is nothing difficult to be implemented, but I am about to start a new huge project and do not know if I should go this way, or use something old fashioned. So I am very curious about your opinion.

Please consider the following notation:

```
class File
{
    FILE *file = nullptr;

    public:

        Result<void> open(const char *fileName);
        Result<void> close();
        Result<size_t> size();
        Result<void> seek(size_t newPosition);
        Result<size_t> position();
        Result<char> readCharacter();
};
```

Lets now analyze an usage example:

```
Result<void> processFile(const char *fileName)
{
    File file;
    auto result = file.open(fileName);
    if (!result.isSuccess())
        return result;

    auto fileSize = file.size();
    if (!fileSize.isSuccess())
        return fileSize;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < fileSize; i++) {
        auto character = file.readCharacter();
        if (!character.isSuccess())
            return character;

        if (character < 'a' || character > 'z')
            return Error::invalidData;

        // processfileCharacter(character);
    }

    return Error::success;
}
```

As you can see, error management becomes extremely simple. Moreover, when I write header-only code, both GCC and MSVC produces very optimal code when optimization is enabled. I very like this notation and do not see any serious disadvantages. But I would love to hear your opinion.

**Implementation**

If you would like to test it, please enjoy the code:

```
enum class Error: int
{
    success,
    unknown,
    invalidData
    // ...
};
```

Result class:

```
template <typename Type = void>
class Result
{
    Error error = Error::success;
    Type data;

    public:

        Result() = default;

        Result(Result &&result) = default;
        Result(const Result &result) = default;
        template <typename OtherType> Result(const Result<OtherType> &result) : error(result.error) {}

        Result & operator =(Result &&result) = default;
        Result & operator =(const Result &result) = default;
        template <typename OtherType> Result & operator =(const Result<OtherType> &result) { error = result; return *this; }

        Result(const Type &data) : data(data) {}
        Result(Type &&data) : data(std::move(data)) {}
        Result(const Error &error) : error(error) {}
        Result(Error &&error) : error(std::move(error)) {}

        operator Type& () { return data; }
        operator const Type& () const { return data; }
        operator const Error() const { return error; }

        bool isSuccess() const { return error == Error::success; }
};
```

Specialization for void:

```
template <>
class Result<void>
{
    Error error = Error::success;

    public:

        Result() = default;

        Result(Result &&result) = default;
        Result(const Result &result) = default;
        template <typename OtherType> Result(const Result<OtherType> &result) : error(result.error) {}

        Result & operator =(Result &&result) = default;
        Result & operator =(const Result &result) = default;
        template <typename OtherType> Result & operator =(const Result<OtherType> &result) { error = result; return *this; }

        Result(const Error &error) : error(error) {}
        Result(Error &&error) : error(std::move(error)) {}

        operator const Error() const { return error; }

        bool isSuccess() const { return error == Error::success; }
};
```

Comment: Why not use exceptions instead? Example code is already bloated with `if (!result.isSuccess())` and suffers from error shadowing.

Comment: It is unclear what this has to do with move semantics.

Comment: Personally I would use *exceptions* and when you do need a return error code there is `std::optional` (I think you should be able to find a `C++11` compatible version somewhere).

Comment: There is a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0323r3.pdf) for a `std::expected`. It seems you are trying to do something similar.

Comment: Having to do an `if()` at every level to decide whether or not to pass the error back up the call stack is bad maintenance and is better done using *exceptions* imo.

Comment: I think this question would be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. I do not think there is anything wrong with your approach iff you do not want to use exceptions or cannot do so for any reason. You may want to have a look at how the LLVM project uses a similar approach in their code: http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Expected.html

Comment: By mentioning move semantics I wanted to point out that the above construction is really efficient .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach has the following major disadvantages:

- it opens your code base to the possibility of silent failures, when you forget to check the result.

  Consider this code instead, as a client code example:

  ```
  Result<void> processFile(const char *fileName)
  {
      File file;
      auto result = file.open(fileName);
      // utnapistim was tired when writing this code and forgot to
      // check the error status in result
      // (this is a bug)

      auto fileSize = file.size(); // (1)
      if (!fileSize.isSuccess())
          return fileSize;

      // ...
      // rest is the same as your example client code

      return Error::success;
  }
  ```

  The code below the missing error check, fails silently: it will execute in a situation it shouldn't, with data that is invalid.

  In this particular case, the code that gets executed (line `(1)`) is on the `File` class, and this *could* work correctly (if the `File` class checks internal state, before getting the size).

  With your approach, whenever you write client code, you have to explicitly remember to handle errors. In most practical cases, **you will assume that File::size checks state before calling a low-level file size function**.

  Don't assume - it leads to bugs.
- it severely inflates all client code, striving to do the job of the compiler. Consider this alternative client code:

  ```
  void processFile(const char *fileName)
  {
      auto file = File{fileName}; // throws on failure
      auto fileSize = file.size(); // executed only on success

      for (size_t i = 0; i < fileSize; i++) {
          auto character = file.readCharacter(); // throws on failure

          if (character < 'a' || character > 'z')
              throw invalidData{'expected alphanumeric value'};

      // processfileCharacter(character);
      }

      return Error::success;
  }
  ```

  You have less client code to maintain, and the code looks simpler

  You have invariants (when you are below the declaration of a `File` instance, you *know* it is valid, without having to add an `if` statement)
- it severely restricts good principles of OO design:

  - what happens when your constructor cannot run? Your `File` class doesn't have one.

If you use exceptions instead, this is a non-issue: exceptions get propagated regardless if you have a test for them (catch block) or not.

Unless you have a strong reason to avoid exceptions, *you should use them for error handling*.

Comment: imho, the last sentence is debatable; not all error conditions are exceptional. If an error condition is not exceptional, the user will need to place checks in its logic flow anyway, making code inflation even worst (not to mention the performance cost, see noexcept and standard containers). Moreover, managing invariants does not come for free, exception safety is not easy. Moreover, code should be simple, but not simplistic; say, a piece of code throwing whenever sqrt(-1) just because it 'looks simpler', it's a wrong piece of code if it works with imaginary numbers ...

Comment: ... ah, I'm not advocating in favor of OP approach, using something like std::expected<> *everywhere* is as bad as using exceptions *everywhere* imho

Comment: What means "exceptional" in this context? If a function can complete its task, it will. If it cannot, it should throw (so that code after its call, only gets executed if the exception is explicitly handled), and so that client code has no responsibility to check a result, before leaving application in a consistent state. Also, exception safety is difficult, but it takes this from error handling (which is just as difficult).

Comment: to me, "exceptional" means recoverable and unexpected; my point is: *if* it's expected (ie, the user *must* handle it in its own logic flow), code will turn out as ugly and fragile (if not more) than the error code version, but with added performance penalty (especially re to containers and the like).